# Moving background to infinite scroll help Swift Sprite Kit

Tags: swift, background, sprite-kit

I'm having trouble understanding what I did wrong here. It's supposed to infinite scroll downwards and I can't fix it. Help!

```
 func moveBackground() {

    let moveBackground = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -self.size.height, duration: 1.0)
    let repeatBackground = SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveBackground)
    let removeBackground = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let sequenceThis = SKAction.sequence([moveBackground, repeatBackground, removeBackground])
}
func repeatBackground() {

    let generateBackground = SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.runBlock(self.moveBackground),
        SKAction.waitForDuration(2.7)])
    let endlessAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(generateBackground)
    runAction(endlessAction)
}



override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    scene?.scaleMode = .AspectFill


    var backgroundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Background.png")
    background.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2)
    background.texture = backgroundTexture
    background.size.width = self.frame.size.width
    background.size.height = self.frame.size.height
    self.addChild(background)

}
```

Whenever I run the app the background just stays in its position and won't move.

Comment: What does it do instead? There's not enough info here to help you

Comment: I edited it. @avery i just dont understand why it wont work

Answer (score 0):

First of all `moveBackground()` doesn't do anything except creating actions, it doesn't run them. You probably forgot to run `runAction(sequenceThis)` in the end.

There are many more issues like, you are removing the sprite for some reason but making action repeat forever, it will remove that sprite again, but nothing is adding it back.

`repeatBackground()` runs `moveBackground()` forever but it doesn't create new background, it just moves one forever.

Lastly `didMoveToView` doesn't call `repeatBackground()` nor `moveBackground()`.

Comment: but how do i make it so that the backgrounds delete after they are off the screen

Comment: @JoshSchlabach You should be more precise when asking a question like this. At the moment it feels too broad. I can only point out what problems I see. You might want not to remove old background but just setting it's position back to the start so it can be reused, then when action runs again it will move it down again.

Answer (score 0):

In `moveBackground()` you are not "running" the action. The result would presumably be that it does nothing.

You need to tell the background to run this action.

```
backgroundView.runAction(sequenceThis)
```